# manipulating strings and use commands with the result in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, unix

I have the following script, which manipulates a string.

```
    #!/bin/bash

diry=$( find . -iname "cassandra.yaml" -exec dirname {} + )

dirgo=${diry:2}

echo $dirgo

cd $dirgo
```

this is the result:

```
cassandra@server:~$ pwd
/opt/cassandra
cassandra@server:~$ ./yaml.sh 
conf
cassandra@cads2001:~$ pwd
/opt/cassandra
```

Prints the directory, But it does not go into the directory.

Maybe i need another kind of variable.

regards.

Comment: Use `pwd` after `cd` command to see current directory.

Comment: try `echo ${dir}go` . Good luck.

Comment: the find command may find your directory, but your current directory may not directly above the directory you found

Comment: I try use cd ${diry:2}, but nothing

Comment: I have the answer. Inside the script goes to the directory, and when finished it returns to the current directory.